# use autofac in asp .net core mvc how to Use conventions to find and register components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac, asp.net-core-1.1

How to use autofac in .NET core to use conventions to find and register components like this

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I found  `builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Where(t=>t.Name.StartsWith("Home"));`

that can't use.
how can Injected xxxService  into controller

Comment: [Did you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)

Comment: Thank you suggested that I read the document, and finally found that I loaded the wrong assembly. i found The ASP.NET Core framework now automatically passes all controllers through service resolution so you don’t have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection)

All you have to do is Register the service with the autofac container. For example, assuming your service types end with 'Service' you could do:

```
     builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then use constructor injection to inject the service into the controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
   private IFooService fooService;
   public HomeController(IFooService fooService)
   {
        this.fooService = fooService
   }
}
```

I believe `RegisterControllers(...)` is supposed to be used for prior versions of ASP.Net.

Comment: RegisterControllers(...) this is used in ASP.NET not in ASP.NET Core thanks. i loked the Microsoft Doc ,finally I found I Loaded the wrong assembly in builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();                        the Parameter 'ssemblies' is wrong。